# Why the PETSC code run in 1 process and doesn't run in 2 processes?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, petsc

This is a simple code from the book *PETSc for Partial Differential Equations: Numerical Solutions in C and Python*. It computes the zero of `atan(x)`. If I run it in one process, it runs properly. However, if I run in two processes, it doesn't run. I really don't know what is wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
#include <petsc.h>

extern PetscErrorCode FormFunction(SNES, Vec, Vec, void*);

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    PetscErrorCode ierr;
    SNES      snes;          // nonlinear solver
    Vec       x, r;          // solution, residual vectors
    PetscReal x0 = 2.0;

    PetscInitialize(&argc,&argv,(char*)0,help);

    ierr = PetscOptionsBegin(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,"","options to atan","");CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = PetscOptionsReal("-x0","initial value","atan.c",x0,&x0,NULL); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = PetscOptionsEnd();CHKERRQ(ierr);

    ierr = VecCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&x); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecSetSizes(x,PETSC_DECIDE,1); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecSetFromOptions(x); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecSet(x,x0); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecDuplicate(x,&r); CHKERRQ(ierr);

    ierr = SNESCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&snes); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = SNESSetFunction(snes,r,FormFunction,NULL); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = SNESSetFromOptions(snes); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = SNESSolve(snes,NULL,x); CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecView(x,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD); CHKERRQ(ierr);

    VecDestroy(&x);  VecDestroy(&r);  SNESDestroy(&snes);
    PetscFinalize();
    return 0;
}

PetscErrorCode FormFunction(SNES snes, Vec x, Vec F, void *ctx) {
    PetscErrorCode ierr;
    const PetscReal  *ax;
    PetscReal        *aF;

    ierr = VecGetArrayRead(x,&ax);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecGetArray(F,&aF);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    aF[0] = atan(ax[0]);
    ierr = VecRestoreArrayRead(x,&ax);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecRestoreArray(F,&aF);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the makefile:

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/rules

atan: atan.o chkopts;-${FLINKER} -o atan atan.o  ${PETSC_LIB}; ${RM} atan.o
```

The command that I use to run in one process:

```
~/petsc/arch-darwin-c-opt/bin/mpiexec -n 1    ./atan  -snes_fd
```

That results in:

```
Vec Object: 1 MPI processes
  type: seq
7.55724e-16
```

The command that I use to run in 2 processes:

```
~/petsc/arch-darwin-c-opt/bin/mpiexec -n 2    ./atan  -snes_fd
```

In this case, result is:

```
[1]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
[1]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[1]PETSC ERROR: or see https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html#valgrind
[1]PETSC ERROR: or try http://valgrind.org on GNU/linux and Apple Mac OS X to find memory corruption errors
[1]PETSC ERROR: configure using --with-debugging=yes, recompile, link, and run 
[1]PETSC ERROR: to get more information on the crash.
[1]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message --------------------------------------------------------------
[1]PETSC ERROR: Signal received
[1]PETSC ERROR: See https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html for trouble shooting.
[1]PETSC ERROR: Petsc Release Version 3.12.4, Feb, 04, 2020 
[1]PETSC ERROR: ./atan on a  named e5705c1d6678 by Unknown Fri Jun  9 11:40:40 2023
[1]PETSC ERROR: Configure options --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --with-silent-rules=0 --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --with-maintainer-mode=0 --with-dependency-tracking=0 --with-debugging=0 --shared-library-extension=_real --with-shared-libraries --with-pic=1 --with-cc=mpicc --with-cxx=mpicxx --with-fc=mpif90 --with-cxx-dialect=C++11 --with-opencl=1 --with-blas-lib=-lblas --with-lapack-lib=-llapack --with-scalapack=1 --with-scalapack-lib=-lscalapack-openmpi --with-mumps=1 --with-mumps-include="[]" --with-mumps-lib="-ldmumps -lzmumps -lsmumps -lcmumps -lmumps_common -lpord" --with-suitesparse=1 --with-suitesparse-include=/usr/include/suitesparse --with-suitesparse-lib="-lumfpack -lamd -lcholmod -lklu" --with-ptscotch=1 --with-ptscotch-include=/usr/include/scotch --with-ptscotch-lib="-lptesmumps -lptscotch -lptscotcherr" --with-fftw=1 --with-fftw-include="[]" --with-fftw-lib="-lfftw3 -lfftw3_mpi" --with-superlu=1 --with-superlu-include=/usr/include/superlu --with-superlu-lib=-lsuperlu --with-superlu_dist=1 --with-superlu_dist-include=/usr/include/superlu-dist --with-superlu_dist-lib=-lsuperlu_dist --with-hdf5-include=/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi --with-hdf5-lib="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/openmpi -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lhdf5 -lmpi" --CXX_LINKER_FLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed --with-hypre=1 --with-hypre-include=/usr/include/hypre --with-hypre-lib=-lHYPRE_core --prefix=/usr/lib/petscdir/petsc3.12/x86_64-linux-gnu-real --PETSC_ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu-real CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC" FCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -ffree-line-length-0" FFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -ffree-line-length-0" CPPFLAGS="-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fPIC" MAKEFLAGS=w
[1]PETSC ERROR: #1 User provided function() line 0 in  unknown file
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 1 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
with errorcode 59.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 15 Terminate: Some process (or the batch system) has told this process to end
[0]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[0]PETSC ERROR: or see https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html#valgrind
[0]PETSC ERROR: or try http://valgrind.org on GNU/linux and Apple Mac OS X to find memory corruption errors
[0]PETSC ERROR: configure using --with-debugging=yes, recompile, link, and run 
[0]PETSC ERROR: to get more information on the crash.
[0]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message --------------------------------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: Signal received
[0]PETSC ERROR: See https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html for trouble shooting.
[0]PETSC ERROR: Petsc Release Version 3.12.4, Feb, 04, 2020 
[0]PETSC ERROR: ./atan on a  named e5705c1d6678 by Unknown Fri Jun  9 11:40:40 2023
[0]PETSC ERROR: Configure options --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --with-silent-rules=0 --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --with-maintainer-mode=0 --with-dependency-tracking=0 --with-debugging=0 --shared-library-extension=_real --with-shared-libraries --with-pic=1 --with-cc=mpicc --with-cxx=mpicxx --with-fc=mpif90 --with-cxx-dialect=C++11 --with-opencl=1 --with-blas-lib=-lblas --with-lapack-lib=-llapack --with-scalapack=1 --with-scalapack-lib=-lscalapack-openmpi --with-mumps=1 --with-mumps-include="[]" --with-mumps-lib="-ldmumps -lzmumps -lsmumps -lcmumps -lmumps_common -lpord" --with-suitesparse=1 --with-suitesparse-include=/usr/include/suitesparse --with-suitesparse-lib="-lumfpack -lamd -lcholmod -lklu" --with-ptscotch=1 --with-ptscotch-include=/usr/include/scotch --with-ptscotch-lib="-lptesmumps -lptscotch -lptscotcherr" --with-fftw=1 --with-fftw-include="[]" --with-fftw-lib="-lfftw3 -lfftw3_mpi" --with-superlu=1 --with-superlu-include=/usr/include/superlu --with-superlu-lib=-lsuperlu --with-superlu_dist=1 --with-superlu_dist-include=/usr/include/superlu-dist --with-superlu_dist-lib=-lsuperlu_dist --with-hdf5-include=/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi --with-hdf5-lib="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/openmpi -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lhdf5 -lmpi" --CXX_LINKER_FLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed --with-hypre=1 --with-hypre-include=/usr/include/hypre --with-hypre-lib=-lHYPRE_core --prefix=/usr/lib/petscdir/petsc3.12/x86_64-linux-gnu-real --PETSC_ARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu-real CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC" FCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -ffree-line-length-0" FFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -ffree-line-length-0" CPPFLAGS="-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fPIC" MAKEFLAGS=w
[0]PETSC ERROR: #1 User provided function() line 0 in  unknown file
[e5705c1d6678:03125] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-api.txt / mpi-abort
[e5705c1d6678:03125] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
[warn] Epoll MOD(1) on fd 23 failed. Old events were 6; read change was 0 (none); write change was 2 (del); close
```

I run it in MacOS using the latest Petsc version (I've just installed). I also run it in Google Colab and the result is exactly the same. You can see the Colab file [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11JnAamlbYN4HX6oqNctfnwMkGRpdw-eo?usp=sharing).

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Fix your formatting and provide a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: Are you sure you mean C++? Code looks like "C" to me, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry, it is C.

Comment: The compiler is gcc, but in parallel, with mpich.

Answer (score 0):

This code, which I think is c/ch4/solns/atan.c in the book (i.e. Exercise 4.4) is solving a 1D equation by Newton's method.  Therefore the Vec has only one entry.  PETSc Vecs need at least one entry per process, though here an issue occurs only inside SNESSolve().  If you comment-out the SNESSolve() line then it will not seg fault, but of course you won't solve the equation.  Note there is no reason to run this example in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed Bueler. I understood now the reason.